# Using Javascript and regex to extract data

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using an rss feed to pull data into my website. One piece of data is a date, which comes in formatted like so: Feb 22 2013

I need to use regex (or an alternate javascript method) to extract JUST the day (22) from the full date. Any idea how i can go about this?

Comment: Would `\d+` work for you?

Comment: Is that the expression??

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: That is the regex. Wrap in delimiters, call its `match` method with the tested string as the argument, and pick the first match if there's any. Are you familiar with Javascript coding?

Comment: wouldnt \d+ leave the year in as well being as that it is a numerical digit?

Comment: /\w{3}\s(\d{2})\s\d{4}/

Comment: It's space delimited, so no. Space is not a number.

Comment: just split it by whitespaces and take the split[1] bit worked arround i guess

Comment: @ilanberci - Should probably be \d{1,2} unless days are prefixed with 0. Also, \w{3} should probably be \w+ in case of non-3-letter months.

Comment: I am familiar with javascript, and use it regularly, but have not worked with RegEx....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fTSCu/ @JCHASE11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
var data= "Feb 22 2012";
var splitted = data.split(" ");
alert(splitted[1]);
```

try it

http://jsfiddle.net/fTSCu/

not the most elegant solution though

Answer (score 2):

```
var parsed = Date.parse("Feb 22 2013");//NaN if invalid
var date = new Date(parsed);
date.getDate() //==22
```